# Create a setup.py

Tags: python

I am quite new to Python and I tried to search before ask but it seem like I chose the wrong keyword and I couldn't find the correct answer that I want.
I have a TSP project that wrote in Python. You can see in the link [here](https://github.com/thovo/aa_practice_project).

I want to pack all of my files and whenever someone clone my repository or copy it, after type some command like this:

```
python setup.py install
```

It will install automatically all dependencies packages that my project needs, like `xlwt` or `prettytable`. After finish installation, he/she can run the program with this command: `python TSP.py`. I tried to read the setup.py of `django` or `bottle` but actually, I can't understand.